# C++/CLI - How effective is garbage collection & is it really working for me?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using C++/CLI and .Net 4.0 (managed c++), my IDE is visual studio 2012 RC.

My program is almost entirely written in C++/CLI (I only have a five lines native code) and I'm wondering how effective garbage collection is and if it's really working for me.

When I start my program (I'm using some forms) it takes about 3-5 MB RAM. But after the program has been running for a while (the same code is running over and over again with new information entered to it) it uses more and more memory (after 5-15 minutes it takes about 10-25 MB RAM) and the amount of RAM only increases?

Why is this? And isn't this exactly what garbage collection should prevent?!

And would it be bad to force garbage collection every minute or so?

Comment: 10–25 MiB of RAM is **nothing**. Expect the GC to kick in once you reach a few hundred.

Comment: Right now, of a total of 120 running processes, I have about 50 using more than 30MiB of RAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this? And isn't this exactly what garbage collection should prevent?!

The garbage collector doesn't (necessarily) run constantly.  It runs *as needed*, and tends to not run often if there is no memory pressure.  If your system has a lot of free memory, the GC will not always run frequently, so you can see memory growth.  This isn't a problem - there is no issue with using "unused" memory, provided it will clean up if the system's gets into a situation where there is more memory pressure.

The garbage collector does still work, however - and you shouldn't worry about trusting it.  You won't be leaking memory with pure managed code - though you may use more memory than you'd otherwise expect at times.

Comment: Would it be bad to force garbage collection every minute or so?

Comment: @HalfEvil Yes, very.  It's counterproductive for many reasons.  It actually messes up the heuristics of the GC, but also just eats up processing time in your program with no benefit.  Remember -there is no harm in using memory, as long as your system doesn't run out.  As long as there is free memory, using it is "free" and doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Okay I see, the problem is that it's (it should be) a pretty small/lightweight program that always should be turned on (for the functions to work). And if the user of the program would look in the task manager and see that my program takes a couple hundred MB of RAM they would possible end it, uninstall and look for a more lightweight option :/ Most people think that a program that takes much RAM slow the computer down :(

Comment: @HalfEvil You'll find that most .NET programs tend to use a lot of RAM, always.  There isn't really a good way to avoid this, as the framework loading itself takes a fair amount of space.  This is a common thing now -as so much uses managed code, that I don't think that mindset is as prevalent as it used to be...

Comment: I suppose that I can't change when GC is going to kick in? (So I can make it kick in when the program uses about 25-50 MB RAM)

Comment: @HalfEvil Nope - there isn't control over the GC process in .NET.  It controlled by the framework itself, and doesn't look at (only) the memory of your process, but rather the memory used by your process in relation to the memory pressure of the entire system at runtime.